# Sqlite3: Inserting multiple rows is still slow

Tags: sqlite

I need to perform about 250 million inserts using sqlite3 and python.

I've wrapped every 500 inserts using SELECT UNION, and also done CREATE INDEX.

But even so, it later becomes slow, performing less than 1 million inserts per hour (about 300 inserts per second)

Is there any way to make it any significantly faster?

Comment: I don't see what SELECT UNION has to do with INSERTs. And generally you want to add your indexes *after* your bulk INSERTs.

Comment: @muistooshort I'm wrapping mulitple inserts into one transaction in a way like INSERT INTO myTable
SELECT "1", "test"
UNION
SELECT "2", "test"
...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [article](http://blog.quibb.org/2010/08/fast-bulk-inserts-into-sqlite/) explains very well the issue of fast insert in sqlite3. It comes with a benchmark of different approaches.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the better/best optimization guides I have read:
[How do I improve the performance of sqlite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711631/how-do-i-improve-the-performance-of-sqlite)

I recently spent some time optimizing an initial load of a large dataset into sqlite and the tips in there helped greatly.  I'd recommend just reading through, no point in me doing a c/p of it.